# What's wrong with this simple jquery get?

Tags: jquery, get

I have code that looks something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myButton_click(){
            alert('got here');
            $.get("myPage.cfm", function(data){alert('load was performed')});
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="myButton" value="My Button" onClick="myButton_click()" />
</body>
</head>
```

The first alert ("got here") shows up, but the "load was performed" doesn't. Is the get being executed? What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**:

I've tried it with "http://www.google.com" instead of "myPage.cfm" to make sure it's not a problem with my page and it's still not alerting...

Comment: You do use Firebug, don't you? What says the "Network" tab?

Comment: Is "myPage.cfm" in the same DIR as this page?  You aren't specifying a location, so I am assuming so.

Comment: What is the URL of this page?

Comment: @Boldewyn - yup, I use Firebug, but never used the network panel... hold on while I activate it :)

Comment: @MattW - yup, I meant to call it "myRelativePath" or something so that would be clear

Comment: Ok, the network panel seems to show that it's being loaded - displaying a "302 Found" (but I've never used it before so may not know what I'm doing)

Comment: Means it's getting redirected in which case the success callback is never called.

Comment: You can't test it with google.com (same origin policy).

Comment: froadie http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @Boldewyn - thanks a LOT! This network tab is amazing! I think I should take a firebug tutorial :) I discover new things about it every day

Comment: @froadie: You're welcome! There are also great extensions, if you miss a functionality: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: 302's are followed, and `success` will be fired eventually. Only 4** and 5** HTTP states won't fire it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), the function you pass as the second parameter to the `$.get` call is only called **on success**. So if your server is returning any kind of error (400, 403, 404, 500 etc.), that function will not be called. If you want a function to be called no matter what, use `complete`:

```
$.get("myPage.cfm").complete(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert("Load was performed");
});
```

Comment: ok, got it. using the network tab (thanks boldewyn :) ), I can see that the page is returning an error.

Answer (score 0):

The callback only executes on success (Http status code in the 200s or 304), try using the longhand [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method and following the advice in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call) SO question for how to handle this response in a reasonable manner.

Comment: Actually that's slightly incomplete, jQuery considers these status codes "successful" `status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304`